# apply diminishing returns across 2 axis with numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How can I use `numpy` to apply a level of diminishing returns across 2 axes.  I'm working with temperature model data for a fixed `(x,y)` location.  So the axes I'm working with is `t_axis` time and the `z_axis` vertical atmosphere.

The values below dont really apply to what would make sense for the normal atmosphere, but lets pretend.

```py
a1=np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)

[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]
```

assume the information above is current forecast model data for my location, and it is predicting a temp of `12°C` at the surface right now.  But when I walk outside its actually `10°C`, so I want to adjust the model data and make that temperature `10°C`.

```py
z_axis=3
t_axis=0
a1[z_axis,t_axis]=10

[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [10 13 14 15]]
```

but really what I want to do apply a level of correction based on 2 variables `t_mod` (diminished returns over time) & `z_mod` (diminished returns through the vertical atmosphere).

```py
correction = -2
t_mod=.05#50%
z_mod=0.25#25%
# how can i generate this array from modifiers 
a2=np.array([

    [0,0,0,0],#6k feet above ground level (agl)
    [0,0,0,0],#4k feet agl
    [.25,.13,0,0],#2k feet agl
    [1,.5,.25,0]#surface
   # ^  ^  ^  ^__ +3 hour
   # |  |  L__ +2 hour
   # |  L__ +1 hour
   # L__ zero hour
])
a1+(a2*correction )

[[ 0.    1.    2.    3.  ]
 [ 4.    5.    6.    7.  ]
 [ 7.5   8.74  8.8  11.  ]
 [10.   12.   13.5  15.  ]]
```

Is this the approach I should be using? If so how can I generate a2 from the `z` and `t` axis modifiers.

Comment: Why is the 4th item of the first row of `a2` `0`?

Comment: 100% of the correction is being applied at [0,3]  | 50% at [1,3] | 25% at [0,2].  If the modifiers are set to 1 ie: 100% the model data is adjusted 100% over time and through the vertical. Each dim represents a level of the atmosphere, each value is a point in time.

Comment: Just looking at the surface values, I see a pattern, except for the fourth item. The surface values, `[1, .5, .25, 0]` decrease exponentially, in a manner given by `0.5**i`. Except for the last value, which should be 0.125 by this equation, but actually is zero. Why is the last value zero?

Comment: That's my mistake.  With the t axis set to `.5` at the mid way point the correction should diminish to `zero`. If I knew how to generate the array I could provide a better example.

Comment: Well, what if you made it diminish linearly, but clamped to be at least 0? So the surface would look like `[1, 0.5, 0, 0]`, subtracting 0.5 each time. The 2k above ground level would look like the previous row, but with 0.25 subtracted, or `[0.75, 0.25, 0, 0]`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this, we use linear stepping in `t` and `z` directions and multiply the t and z axes for points inside the matrix:

```
def shock_2d(t_mod, z_mod, n=4):
    ts = np.maximum(1 - np.arange(n)*t_mod,0)
    zs = np.maximum(1 - np.arange(n)*z_mod,0)
    shock = zs.reshape(-1,1) @ ts.reshape(1,-1)
    return np.flipud(shock)
```

eg

```
shock_2d(t_mod = 0.5, z_mod = 0.25)

Out:
array([[0.25 , 0.125, 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.5  , 0.25 , 0.   , 0.   ],
       [0.75 , 0.375, 0.   , 0.   ],
       [1.   , 0.5  , 0.   , 0.   ]])
```

and

```
shock_2d(t_mod = 0.05, z_mod = 0.25)

Out:
array([[0.25  , 0.2375, 0.225 , 0.2125],
       [0.5   , 0.475 , 0.45  , 0.425 ],
       [0.75  , 0.7125, 0.675 , 0.6375],
       [1.    , 0.95  , 0.9   , 0.85  ]])
```

the last argument, `n`, is the size of the matrix